# Technologie : un anglicisme ?

Tags: anglicismes

[image]

Je ne comprends pourquoi Google parle d'anglicisme.

Comment: On dirait qu'en français, le suffixe -logie désigne un champ d'études, une science, plutôt qu'un objet ou un ensemble d'objets. Néanmoins la deuxième acceptation est assez répandue.

Comment: Voir http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/technique-technologie-a23383245 mais ça fait au moins 40 ans qu'on parle de nouvelles technologies donc on peut clairement considérer que ce sens à été adopté.

Comment: On ne peut pas dire que ce soit Google qui parle d'anglicisme, Google ne que reproduire le début de la définition du *Robert* qu'on a en entier en cliquant sur le lien. Et *Robert* ne signale un anglicisme que dans l'emploi dans TIC.

Comment: La technologie de soufflage du verre... ;-)